# Question about LeetCode 2 and linked list

Tags: linked-list

I am learning linked list recently and was stuck at LeetCode No.2. I know that linked list can have a head without any data but a reference(link) to the first node containing data in the list. In this case it seems both l1 and l2 doesn't have this kind of head? Also, the method return head.next not head, does that mean that the result is also a list without this kind of head? Then in which case shall we use a list with a head mentioned above?

Solution as follows:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        int carry = 0;
        ListNode head = new ListNode(0), p = head;
        while (l1 != null || l2 != null || carry != 0) {
            int sum = carry;
            if (l1 != null) { sum += l1.val; l1 = l1.next; } 
            if (l2 != null) { sum += l2.val; l2 = l2.next; }
            p.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
            p = p.next;
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        return head.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that linked list can have a head without any data but a reference(link) to the first node containing data in the list.

This is actually not the normal way to store a linked list. The "head without any data" can be misleading as it is not clear that this node has no data. If you would return such a list, Leet Code would not treat that first node any different from the other nodes: its data would be considered relevant.

> it seems both l1 and l2 doesn't have this kind of head?

That's correct.

> does that mean that the result is also a list without this kind of head?

Yes, and that is what Leet Code expects.

> Then in which case shall we use a list with a head mentioned above?

It is not an absolute requirement to use it, but it makes the code a bit easier. It is a temporary dummy node, that is not returned at the end.

Here is how the code would look when you would not create that extra node:

```java
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        int carry = 0;
        ListNode head = null, p = null;
        while (l1 != null || l2 != null || carry != 0) {
            int sum = carry;
            if (l1 != null) { sum += l1.val; l1 = l1.next; } 
            if (l2 != null) { sum += l2.val; l2 = l2.next; }
            ListNode node = new ListNode(sum % 10);
            if (head == null) {
                head = node;
            } else {
                p.next = node;
            }
            p = node;
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

Notice that now the body of the loop must check in which case it is: is this the first node? Then `head` must reference it. If not, the previous node's `next` attribute must reference it. It is a pity that in *each* iteration this check is performed, while it really is only needed the first time. The use of the dummy node makes this unnecessary.